# div element gets transparent while scrolling while using the position:sticky in css

Tags: css

Hi I am having a CSS object which has position set as sticky so that it stays when scrolled. But when it traverses above other elements like li tags it gets transparent.

```
.nav-menu {
  width: 400px;
  height: 62px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #0c5061;
}
```

I have tried using opacity:1 for the elements but it doesn't seems to work. What else can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s likely that your menu is behind/under the scrolling content. Try setting `z-index: 99`. (99 is arbitrary here. 1 might also work, depending on whether you have other content with z-index.)